# Notepad++ Drag to ftp

Tags: ftp, notepad++

I'm using both explorer and NppFTP plugins for NP++. Is there a way to drag and drop a file from the local explorer window to the remote ftp one?

Answer (score 0):

Use a native FTP client like [Filezilla](http://www.filezilla.de/) for example. With Filezilla you can drag your files to the server.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that Stony. If np++ would allow me to do this i'd skip using a native ftp client :) But probably Dreamweaver can do this (it popped into my mind just now). I'll have to check it out.

Comment: Yes but i think there is a small difference between Dreamweaver and a plugin for Notepad++ ^^ i think a few hundret dollars. I have tried notepad++ before a few weeks but i was not so afraid about. But i think the main problem is that the main drag and drop function is for a file to open in the editor.